# How to add our application into iAD network

Tags: iphone, app-store

Could you tell me how to add the application into iAD network?

Please give me advice!

Thuong.

Comment: no search engines available at your location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google instantly brings up the well known raywenderlich site with this tutorial  http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app

Comment: or are you asking how to advertise your own app? that is through itunes connect or the apple developer site.

Comment: I added iAD banner into my app already. But just want to know how it works? I only see test banner on there? How does other application come to iAD banner in my app?

Comment: you wont see actual ads during testing. as long as you followed the tutorial and have your app id set up for iAds then you will receive the test ad during testing and actual ads when app is published.